# ¿Cómo redireccionar al presionar la etiqueta <i> en HTML5?

Tags: html5

Tengo la siguiente etiqueta, la cual muestra un pequeño icono de facebook, quisiera que al darle click me redireccione a facebook, lo intenté de dos formas pero no funciona:

**Forma 1:**

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity" href="https://www.facebook.com"></i>
```

**Forma 2:**

```
 <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com"></a>
</i>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La **solución** es la etiqueta `<a>` por fuera del `<i>`

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity">
</i></a>
```

**Ejemplo**: (de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560755/how-can-i-add-an-href-to-a-fontawesome-icon-and-word-below-it) de SO)

```css
a.icon-block {
    display:inline-block;
    width:10em;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

a.icon-block i,
a.icon-block span {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<a href="/home" class="icon-block">
<i class="icon-home icon-4x"></i>
<span>Home</span>
</a>
<a href="/admin" class="icon-block">
<i class="icon-th icon-4x"></i>
<span>Admin</span>
</a>
<a href="/settings" class="icon-block">
<i class="icon-cog icon-4x"></i>
<span>Settings</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <a "URL" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-youtube"></span> youtube
  </a>
```